# What does the community think about creating a [sensors] tag (or one or more tags like it)?

Tags: discussion, tags

Our community currently has a [gps](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps) tag, but nothing for other types of sensors, such as gyroscopes, accelerometers, temperature gauges, step counters, proximity sensors, and light sensors.

What do you think of adding a [sensors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensors) tag, or more specific tags for individual types of sensors?

I'm leaning towards adding a [sensors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensors) tag now, and only adding tags for individual types of sensors (besides GPS) if the demand warrants.

What do you think?

Comment: Good question, thanks! Have you identified a group of 10+ questions the tag would match? That would be a good indicator then. Have you not been able to identify at least 5 questions warranting it? That could be an indicator against it.

Comment: You're welcome Izzy.  I've definitely identified 10+ questions that would match [tag:sensors].  I'm going to look through everything when (if?) I have some time and report back for specific sensors.

Comment: Thanks! Then count my upvote as a "yes, please". Not sure if specific sensors tags (like one for gyro, proximity etc) are justified. But a generic one should be fine.